# How I can display feature installation progress in my bundle (bootstrapper)?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

I want to display feature installation progress in my managed bootstrapper (bundle). How can I do this?

Comment: Since you specifically asked about displaying features, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674015/3923734) applies, but you mentioned that you are using a bootstrapper, so maybe it would be sufficient for you to display the name of the **product** that is currently being installed?

Answer (score 4):

A good example is to download the [WiX source code](http://wixtoolset.org/releases) and see how they did it in their managed bootstrapper.

The bulk of the progress bar code is located in *src\Setup\WixBA\ProgressViewModel.cs*

**Update** regarding showing which feature is being installed: Windows Installer doesn't really work like that. It does not install feature A, then feature B, then feature C. Instead it goes through the [sequence table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and performs the necessary operations across all features.

Ex: Here is a [suggested install execute sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When Windows Installer encounters the InstallFiles action, it installs all the files. When Windows Installers encounters the WriteRegistryValues action, it writes all the registry values.

Comment: I have seen the source code. But I want to display the name of the feature which is installing.

Comment: Windows installer doesn't really work like that. See my edit.